# ITextSharp New lines in Dictionary

Tags: c#, itext

Currently stuck producing Piece Info (despite the deprecation) onto PDFs, and I'm having an issue meeting the requirement due to how itextsharp is spitting out the dictionary into the PDF.

Basically I'm just doing

```
dictionary.Put(Field1, new PdfString("Value1"));
dictionary.Put(Field2, new PdfString("Value2"));
dictionary.Put(Field3, new PdfString("Value3"));
dictionary.Put(Field4, new PdfString("Value4"));
```

which results in this in the PDF:

```
/Field1(Value1)/Field2(Value2)/Field3(Value3)/Field4(Value4)
```

This should be absolutely fine...but since the parser of the people I am producing this for reads each line individually...I need to produce it so that it outputs into the PDF like so:

```
/Field1(Value1)
/Field2(Value2)
/Field3(Value3)
/Field4(Value4)
```

Anyone know of a way to get iTextSharp dictionaries to toss a new line between each entry?

Comment: You can try and patch iText to do that. But actually you should instead ask those people to fix their parser as what you describe means that it is broken.

Comment: if only that was an actual option...but im sure you know how that goes.

Comment: @Johannes shows in his answer how to extend the iTextSharp `PdfDictionary` class to do this. As long as you create the dictionary objects yourself, you can use that approach and create your own variant of that class. If the dictionary objects are not generated in your code and you cannot use your own variant, simply patch the same method in iTextSharp itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your ownn PdfDictionary implementation and override `ToPdf(...)` and use this instead of the original

```
public class MyPdfDictionary : PdfDictionary
{
  public override void ToPdf (PdfWriter writer, Stream os)
  {
    // Do it your way
  }
}
```

Here you can find the original implementation [PdfDictionary](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/633699c65df566d9cde1c6013d9739f595498c88/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfDictionary.cs#L128)

EDIT: now I tried it myself and works as intended. I only added one line, the rest is a copy of the code from the link above:

```
  public class CustomPdfDictionary : PdfDictionary
  {
    public override void ToPdf (PdfWriter writer, Stream os)
    {
      PdfWriter.CheckPdfIsoConformance (writer, PdfIsoKeys.PDFISOKEY_OBJECT, this);
      os.WriteByte ((byte)'<');
      os.WriteByte ((byte)'<');

      // loop over all the object-pairs in the Hashtable
      PdfObject value;
      foreach (KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject> e in hashMap)
      {
        value = e.Value;
        e.Key.ToPdf (writer, os);
        int type = value.Type;
        if (type != PdfObject.ARRAY && type != PdfObject.DICTIONARY && type != PdfObject.NAME && type != PdfObject.STRING)
          os.WriteByte ((byte)' ');
        value.ToPdf (writer, os);
        // Customization start
        os.Write (new byte[] { 13, 10 }, 0, 2);
        // Customization end
      }
      os.WriteByte ((byte)'>');
      os.WriteByte ((byte)'>');
    }
  }
```

And here is the code using it:

```
  using (var document = new Document (PageSize.A4))
  using (var outputStream = new FileStream ("D:\\Temp\\result.pdf", FileMode.Create))
  using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance (document, outputStream))
  {
    document.Open ();
    var dictionary = new CustomPdfDictionary ();
    dictionary.Put (new PdfName ("Field1"), new PdfString ("Value1"));
    dictionary.Put (new PdfName ("Field2"), new PdfString ("Value2"));
    dictionary.Put (new PdfName ("Field3"), new PdfString ("Value3"));
    dictionary.Put (new PdfName ("Field4"), new PdfString ("Value4"));
    dictionary.Put (new PdfName ("Field5"), new PdfString ("Value5"));
    pdfWriter.AddToBody (dictionary);

    document.Add (new Paragraph ("Hello World!"));

    document.Close ();
  }
```

and the resulting PDF looks like predicted as you can see in stream `1 0 obj`

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Field1(Value1)
/Field2(Value2)
/Field3(Value3)
/Field4(Value4)
/Field5(Value5)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Length 65/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœ+är
á22U°04WIá2PÐ5´ 1ôÝBÒ¸4<RsròÂó‹rR5C²€j@*\C¸¹ Çi°
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Resources<</Font<</F1 2 0 R>>>>/Contents 3 0 R/Parent 4 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[5 0 R]>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 4 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Producer(iTextSharp’ 5.5.13.3 ©2000-2022 iText Group NV \(AGPL-version\))/CreationDate(D:20220414220947+02'00')/ModDate(D:20220414220947+02'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000363 00000 n 
0000000120 00000 n 
0000000451 00000 n 
0000000251 00000 n 
0000000502 00000 n 
0000000547 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 8/Root 6 0 R/Info 7 0 R/ID [<d852ba3dcf1f78129453dbef9be1a4e5><d852ba3dcf1f78129453dbef9be1a4e5>]>>
%iText-5.5.13.3
startxref
712
%%EOF
```

PS: I'm not sure if this now violates ISO-32000 but it's the result you wanted

Comment: feels like this is definitely on the right track, though im currently struggling to get it right. I took there code and added a simple change to it

os.WriteByte((byte)'\n');

at the bottom of their keyvaluepair foreach loop. However this seemed to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: so to test I just changed it to

os.WriteByte((byte)'|');

And this works, slapping bars exactly where I would need the line feeds. So i'm not quite sure whats going on. Still trying random things and reading the itextsharp code to see if I can figure it out.

This also breaks the PdfReader though...so hopefully a new line wouldn't do that once I can get it inserted.

Comment: I think you should add, after `value.ToPdf(writer, os);` `os.WriteByte (13); os.WriteByte (10);`  but i didn't tried that myself

Comment: no dice. Ive tried about 4 ways of getting LF characters and all just seem to just disappear. It feels like any whitespace character does it because I can't get a space to stick either.

Comment: hmm...i wonder what is wiping these out, because what I just realized was that the LFs stay for the final page, they are lost for each previous page (Im looping through and adding the data to all pages)

Comment: @Finuve I tried it now myself and it works like intended. Perhaps you need to add logic so that the last \r\n is omited or you want an extra \r\n before the first element of the dictionary. But as proof of concept it's working

Comment: yea this is the weird place im in now after my recent discovery, its working, but only for the last page, all previous pages are on a single line. Its like its getting lost after reopening the reader and catalog to do the next page.

Have you tried looping multiple pages and adding it? If so is it working? and of course could you share the code if it is.

Thanks

Comment: @Finuve could you please update your question with your updated code so I don't have to invent it again ;-) thx ... than I can try it on my side

Comment: actually I found a solution, the issue seems to stem from opening and closing the reader, which I was doing between each page update. It seems like something in the PdfReader was causing it to get rid of excess.

Which honestly I shouldn't have been doing that anyway, so as long as I do a single reader open, do all the catalog additions, then close the reader, it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inserting PdfStrings into your dictionary then write a class that overrides the PdfString's ToPdf() method instead of overriding PdfDictionary.

public class PdfNewLine : PdfString
{
public PdfNewLine(string name): base(name)
{
}

```
public override void ToPdf(PdfWriter writer, Stream os)
{
    PdfWriter.CheckPdfIsoConformance(writer, PdfIsoKeys.PDFISOKEY_OBJECT, this);
    byte[] bytes = GetBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer();
    buffer.Append(bytes);
    buffer.Append('\n');
    bytes = StringUtils.EscapeString(buffer.ToByteArray());
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the idea, but this ends up producing new character within the value parenthesis, and creates it as the actual \n, ends up looking like this

/Field1(Value1\n)/Field2(Value2\n)/Field3(Value3\n)/Field4(Value4\n)